# Macbook Lion Recovery Disk Utilities cannot detect newly installed SSD

Tags: macos, ssd, disk-utility, recovery, bootable-disk

I just installed the SSD and I cannot detect the SSD in Disk Utilities of the recovery disk. Even trying to restore from time machine backup it cannot find any disk it can restore to. I am restoring Mac OS X Lion backup and using the Lion bootable USB stick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Boot into Recovery from the USB.
2. Instead of opening Disk Utility, open Terminal instead.
3. Run the command `diskutil list` to see that your drive is being recognised. It should list two disks, one being your bootable drive, the other your SSD, and provide you with a disk identifier (such as `disk0`). If it doesn't show up, check that you have installed it properly.
4. If it is showing up, then type `diskutil partitionDisk disk0 GPT JHFS+ MacHD` to correctly set the partition map to GPT and create a HFS+ Journaled volume. Change `disk0` to the appropriate identifier for your SSD. You can rename the 'MacHD' volume later in Disk Utility or Finder, if you wish.
5. Quit Terminal.

You should now be able to pick up the disk in Disk Utility and Time Machine to restore your backup.

Comment: So turned out that in the morning I checked the internal cable using my iPhone camera and found out that the SSD needed to be raised a bit in order for it to be correctly mounted in the slot. Installing it correctly made it show up. But this is good to know for someone who wants to format using command line.