# SSD not selectable for Yosemite installation

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, install

When I try to install Yosemite the SSD is not found. the Disk Utility lists the SSD, but does not give me the possibility to erase the disk.
Any advices?
Thanks

Comment: Please start Terminal.app and enter `diskutil list` and `diskutil cs list` and add the output to your question

Comment: If one of the below answers has solved your issue, please mark it as the correct answer to move it out of the "Unanswered" section. If your issue hasn't been solved, please provide more information about what happened when you tried the below answers.

Answer (score 1):

Are you booted from another drive or [Internet Recovery](http://support.apple.com/en-is/HT4718) and, if so, are you able to repartition instead of erase the disk using Disk Utility?

1. Select the drive in the Sidebar
2. Select the "Partition" tab
3. Change the "Partition Layout" to "1 Volume" (or however many volumes you wish the drive to have)
4. Click "Options" and change the partition map to "GUID Partition Table" and click "Okay"
5. Name the partition whatever you would like and set the format to "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)"
6. Click "Apply"

If everything went according to plan, you should be able to install Yosemite from the OS X installer. If not, you can try my solution posted [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/161628/104399) to sort it out via Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

**[ON HOLD]**

1. Start  `Terminal` and enter following command at the Terminal prompt:

   > diskutil cs list

   This will give you a list of CoreStorage volumes on your system.
2. Copy the Logical Volume Group (LVG) alphanumeric UUID of your CoreStorage volume. The LVG should be the first UUID listed and it’s the one you want to delete.
3. Next, run the following command:

   > diskutil cs delete UUID

   This will delete your CoreStorage volume and reformat it as a standard HFS+ volume.